# Is there a way to retrieve eclipse executed git commands?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm a regular git user, and I'm building some shortcuts in eclipse to activate some EGit functions.

I'm a bit wary of what is EGit doing (especially the `synchronize workspace` operations), and I was wondering if I could make EGit show **what git commands** it was using.

Do you know of an option to make it log to the console, or generally, how to find out which commands got executed?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[EGit](https://github.com/eclipse/egit) does not use the git executables. It reproduces, with the help of [JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit), what the executables would do.

Git executables store the versioning state of a project in a number of files under the .git folder (branches, refs, commit objects, tags and so on).

EGit and JGit do the same.

---

For example:

A commit with git executables:

```
git commit -m "My commit message"
```

Would be executed in Java through EGit with [CommitOperation.commit()](https://github.com/eclipse/egit/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/op/CommitOperation.java#L232), which uses JGit's [CommitCommand.call()](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommand.java#L148), which [builds](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommand.java#L216) and [inserts](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/internal/storage/file/ObjectDirectoryInserter.java#L112) a commit object, [which are representend through files](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/internal/storage/file/ObjectDirectory.java#L555).

---

There is no clear mapping between EGit's UI operations and their meaning as regular git commands, at least not to my knowledge.

One can go through ([EGit](https://github.com/eclipse/egit), [JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit), [git](https://github.com/git/git))'s code and look for what is happening under the hood, though.

---

EDIT: a pgm package in JGit provides the [inverse mapping](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/src/org/eclipse/jgit/pgm): "Command-line interface Git commands implemented using JGit ("pgm" stands for program)"

---

EDIT: A not-merged Eclipse patch exists for logging what Egit does under the hood: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/103342/

Comment: As I have written an answer to my own question, @Franz-Ebner, please let me know if it satisfies the bounty you have set.

Answer (score 3):

Please go to .git folder of your project. There will be a log folder like in my case (D:\Repo\GIT.git\logs)

all git command executed by eclipse are logged in respective branch file.

a sample of log is

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 27f2e02544d389eb2412c1d467cc99f1786cd662 fanishshukla  1409137288 +0530    commit (initial): First Draft for Jboss
27f2e02544d389eb2412c1d467cc99f1786cd662 6d5634200cfdf6adf7c00ae70004326d2741e3a2 fanishshukla  1409557422 +0530    commit: fast response
6d5634200cfdf6adf7c00ae70004326d2741e3a2 32dbcfa55452b1a89861f422cfc7f90d26435d8c fanishshukla  1409557443 +0530    commit: fast response

Answer (score 2):

What I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20395391/1300626):

There's a bug regarding this requirement:

Bug 349551 - Log EGit activities into a console
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349551

Comment: It's worth noting that EGit does not actually run regular `git` commands but has its own implementation. Any log that EGit will emit in the future is an approximation of corresponding commands for regular `git`.

Comment: Though I found the wanted answer, I'm willing to reward any further research. So if you could describe that a bit clearer and probably offer an example, the bounty is yours!

Answer (score 0):

How about `git reflog` to view command history of git