# How to see egit console output

Tags: egit

I want to see the output of the egit (eclipse plugin for git) when doing some operations like pulling, pushing in eclipse, just like the SVN plugin. Anyone knows how to do it?

I'm using Elcipse Kepler which already contains egit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048070/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-eclipse-executed-git-commands

Answer (score 2):

You can install additional tool from opensource contribution
http://rherrmann.github.io/gonsole/repository/

Look at post http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/07/09/gonsole-weeks-a-git-console-for-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that this is not yet implemented in EGit, see [bug 349551](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349551).